# Fullcalendar: Labeling the current day with "Today" in agendaWeek view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to label the current day with "Today" but cannot get it to work.

I am trying some simple js:

```
$('.fc-sat').text('Today');
```

But the result is:

[image: weekview example today]

and as soon as I navigate to the next week and back, it is disappearing.

I could not find an option for this specific label in the docs either.

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar uses `.fc-today` class for the current day. Hence, `$('.fc-today').text('Today');` should work.

Comment: This inserts "Today" directly below the weekday's name, similar to the screenshot above, but does not change the weekday's name.